# Many2many field depends on another Many2many field

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

On my module I need that when I select departments, only the employees of selected departments appear

```html
        

employee_id0 = fields.Many2many('hr.employee', string='Employee', index=True)
department_id = fields.Many2many('hr.department', string="Department", store=True, required=True)
```

```html
<field name="department_id"  attrs="{'readonly':[('affec_type','=','category')],'invisible':[('affec_type','=','category')]}" widget="many2many_checkboxes"/>
<field name="employee_id0"  attrs="{'invisible':[('affec_type','=','category')]}"  widget="many2many_checkboxes"  domain="[('department_id', 'in',department_id)]"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write an `on_change` method of `department_id`. and fetch all employees related to the departments that you have selected. And return to `employee_id`.

Its just a sample code.

```
@api.depends('department_id')
@api.onchange("department_id")
def _onchange_department_id(self):
    vals = {}
    data = self.env['hr.employee'].search([('departmentt_id','in',self.department_id.ids)])
    ids = list(data.ids)
    vals['domain'] = {
        "employee_id": [("id", "in", ids)],
    }

    return vals
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: thanks for trying to help but it raise an error when I select more than one department

Comment: raise ValueError("Expected singleton: %s" % self)
ValueError: Expected singleton: hr.department(1, 2)